# Spring Boot with Angular on Wildfly getting circular view path error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, wildfly

On `Wildfly`, I have deployed Spring Boot application with Angular FE, which `dist` folder files are in `src/main/resources/static/`. Application starts without any errors and all REST services are available and serving requests. App is exposed on root context path (/).

When I proceed to *`my-wildfy-host.com:8543/`* I have following error:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/error] due to exception [Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)]: javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

When I run the application locally using embedded Tomcat server, everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.my-app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>my-app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy-test</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.14</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>my-app</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                            <hostname>${wildfly.host}</hostname>
                            <username>${wildfly.user}</username>
                            <password>${wildfly.password}</password>
                            <port>${wildfly.port}</port>
                            <filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename>
                            <server-groups>
                                <server-group>${wildfly.server-group}</server-group>
                            </server-groups>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <commands>
                                <command>/server-group=${wildfly.server-group}:restart-servers(blocking=true)</command>
                            </commands>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                                    <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```